# Which NVIDIA driver should I use?

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I have an NVIDIA GeForce 9500 GT.

I'm currently using `nvidia-331` since the `Nouveau` open drivers were giving me some trouble.

But I have several other drivers to select, see:

[image]

What are the differences between them and which one should I select?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The versions are as follows:

- `nvidia-331`: the current release
- `nvidia-173`: an old legacy binary driver, supporting (much) older cards
- `nvidia-304`: a more recent legacy binary driver, supporting older cards
- `nvidia-331-updates`: the update channel for the current release (but it's the same as the version in `nvidia-331` now)
- `nvidia-304-updates`: the update channel for `nvidia-304`
- `nouveau`: the `nouveau` free driver

Update channels contain new versions available for testing; once a version has been tested it is made available in the normal channel.

If `nouveau` isn't working for you, then `nvidia-331` is the appropriate version, since it supports your card. You'd only use one of the legacy versions with an older card, or if the current driver is causing problems (as pointed out by [Mark](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/62988/mark)). You could use the update channel if you want to try the very latest (untested) versions, but there isn't anything new there currently.

Comment: Very thorough answer, thank you very much Stephen!

Comment: The other reason you'd use one of the legacy versions is if the current driver is causing problems, though this is a far more common situation with ATI than with NVidia.

Answer (score 4):

Since the other drivers are legacy drivers or a nouveau driver you should choose the first one. Can you translate me what stands in the 1. and 4. brackets?

Comment: You mean `(privativo, probado) & (privativo)`? That means `(closed, tested) & (closed)`, where `closed` us used as in `closed driver`.

Comment: Then the first one since it's been tested.

Comment: It means proprietary, i.e. not open source (código abierto).